# SQL Query to determine periods from a history table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've got a history table that takes snapshots of a user's historical status.  For simplicity, let's call it "UserFooHistory".  Now I want to write a query to find out the total amount of time that the user's Foo was disabled.  So with the following sample data:

```
UserId  Date        FooEnabled
------  ----        ----------
123     2015-12-01  true
123     2015-12-04  false
123     2015-12-06  false
123     2015-12-09  true
123     2015-12-11  true
123     2015-12-12  false
123     2015-12-14  true
```

From this data, I would want to see a result of 7 days (Foo was disabled from 12/4 - 12/9, and then from 12/12 - 12/14).

What query would get this result efficiently?  I suspect it'll be something involving `LEAD()` or `LAG()`, but given the fact that you can have redundant history records in the middle of a period, it gets a little more complicated...

Comment: I would probably use LAG() to find the time since last change. Then you can sum everything up easily either using a CTE or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `LEAD/LAG` is the way to go. Try this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Lead(dates) 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY userid 
                    ORDER BY dates) lead_date,* 
         FROM   yourtable) 
SELECT userid, 
       Sum(Datediff(day, dates, lead_date)) 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  fooenabled = 'false' 
GROUP  BY userid
```

- [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b39e/5)